# How to deactivate the message processor from the sequence?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working with WSO2 EI.

When a sequence fails I have the need to deactivate a message processor

How can I deactivate the message processor from the sequence?

Thank you!

This if for Linux Server, WSO2 EI - 6.4.0 and JDK is this: 1.8.0_201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple [class mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator) to access the JMX endpoint of the EI to deactivate the message processor. And refer the class mediator in your relevant sequence. Following is a sample class mediator. Here I'm deactivating the message processor named testPro.

```
public class MsgProDeactivator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        try {
            Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String[] credentials = new String[]{"admin", "admin"};
            env.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

            String url = "service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi";
            JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL(url);
            JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(target, env);
            MBeanServerConnection remote = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

            String beanDef = "org.apache.synapse:Type=Message Forwarding Processor view,Name=testPro";
            ObjectName bean = new ObjectName(beanDef);

            remote.invoke(bean, "deactivate", null, null);
            connector.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

For more info : http://imesh.github.io/how-to-activatedeactivate-message-processors-in-wso2-esb-with-mbeans/

Comment: it works correctly, I had to change the org.apache.synapse: Type to a simple processor and the name of the processor I have set it variable and it works perfect, Thank you very much